# ItemsControl with only custom subelements

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I would like to build a custom component that layouts its childs in either a `StackPanel` or a `Grid` (with variable row count, which makes me consider the `StackPanel` instead). The items are custom elements/objects that just hold some configuration, based on which a few controls are created to display them (some labels and text boxes).

Ideally, the component should be used somehow like this (where `SpecializedCustomPanelItem` is a subtype of `CustomPanelItem`):

```
<CustomPanel>
    <CustomPanelItem Param1="value A" Param2="value B">Text</CustomPanelItem>
    <CustomPanelItem Param1="value C">Other text</CustomPanelItem>
    <SpecializedCustomPanelItem>More text</SpecializedCustomPanelItem>
    <!-- The number of items is variable -->
</CustomPanel>
```

I’ve read on the `ItemsControl` for a while now, and it fits my needs rather well. I would create simply types for the items, and make data templates for them available from inside the `ItemsControl`. Then they should already render fine.

However I would like to require the items inside that `ItemsControl` to be of a specific type (i.e. `CustomPanelItem` or a subtype). I actually thought that the `ItemsControl` would allow this, just like you within a `ComboBox` or a `MenuItem`, but it turns out that it actually allows any subtype, and if necessary wraps them in a item container.

So I have been thinking if an `ItemsControl` is actually what I am looking for, as I do not want any “fancy” things like selection or scrolling which most of those controls implement. I actually only want to build a simple interface to a common pattern in the application that auto generates those components and layouts them in a `Grid`/`StackPanel`.

Should I still be using the `ItemsControl` or rather build some more custom component?

Comment: Are you going to bind your items from your viewmodel or are they just statically declared in xaml?

Comment: They are statically declared, but their contents (values inside the generated text boxes) will probably get a binding.

Comment: In that case you know at compile time what types you have added to the panel. There is no chance this will go wrong at runtime if its ok at compile time. So is a check like this not a fit case for a unit test rather than a runtime check?

Comment: So you basically think that using a ItemsControl with appropriate templates for the items would be fine? Hmm…

Comment: Exactly! Infact why do you even want a custom component? Does a ListBox not server your purpose? You can change the listbox's ItemsPanel to whatever type you want. Change it to a stack panel and then apply different templates for the different listbox items and you will be good to go.

Comment: I’m actually not sure about it; but doesn’t a ListBox usually bring selection features with it? Given that I only want to use it as a “generator” for standard controls, I don’t need that at all. So I was actually thinking of just using the standard ItemsControl, which already comes with a StackPanel.

Comment: Ok. Then you can change the ItemsPanel of the ItemsControl to whatever type you want. I don't think you need a CustomPanel. You just need multiple templates for your items.

Comment: Good, thanks, I’ll give that a try. Would you mind writing a summary or something as an answer, so I have something to accept? ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds perfect for an `ItemsControl`

You can set it's `ItemsPanelTemplate` to define the kind of panel which will hold your items, and set the `ItemContainerTemplate` to define how to draw each item.

If items should be drawn differently based on what type they are, I'd suggest using implicit DataTemplates instead of setting the `ItemContainerTemplate`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:BasePanelItem}">
        <my:CustomPanelItem Param1="{Binding Param1}" Param2="{Binding Param2}" Content="{Binding SomeValue}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:SpecializedPanelItem}">
        <my:SpecializedCustomPanelItem Content="{Binding SomeValue}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>


<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <my:CustomPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

You mentioned that you wanted to perhaps use a dynamically created Grid instead of a StackPanel as well. If you do, you might be interested in some [GridHelpers](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/) I have posted on my blog. This would allow you to bind the number of Columns/Rows on the `Grid` in the `ItemsPanelTemplate`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid local:GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}"
                  local:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowIndex}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case you don't really need a custom component. Changing the ItemsPanel type to  whatever type you need + multiple templates for the Items should do the trick.

However to answer the question in the heading: If you want to force an items control to only accept a certain type of items, you will have to create

a. A CustomItemsControl
b. A CustomItemsControlItem

Then for the CustomItemsControl you should declare the attribute

```
[StyleTypedProperty(Property = "ItemContainerStyle", StyleTargetType = typeof(CustomItemsControlItem))]
```

Then you also will need to

```
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new CustomItemsControlItem(); 
        // You can throw an exception here
    }

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is CustomItemsControlItem;
    }
```

If memory serves this should force the ItemsControl to not allow other types to be added as children and should throw exceptions. You could then do some magic inside CustomItemsControlItem by defining some DependencyProperties which you can then set when adding the items in XAML.

But yet if you have multiple types in your ViewModel that you want to display correctly, the correct way is still to provide multiple templates for the CustomItemsControlItem targetting your ViewModel types.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1, thats what we used for our "Open Windows Preview Carousel" control where the item can only be `Window` or `Popup`.